# 2D Twig Array - printing out the content dynamically

Tags: twig

I'm trying to print out a table with keys and values from a 2d-array in twig. The only issue is, that I'm trying to get the values and keys dynamically printed depending on the twig result I get back.

The array I'm getting back from another function can be different with every call, so my goal would be to write a function once instead of multiple times depending on the typ of data I recive.

The array I get is in `{{ tableContent }}`.

One example of the values are:

```
{
    ["Type"] => string(4) "2021"
    ["Description"] => string(11) "Stundenlohn"
    ["Symbol"] => string(3) "ABC"
}, {
    ["Type"] => string(4) "2024"
    ["Description"] => string(9) "Something"
    ["Symbol"] => string(3) "XYZ"
}
```

so in this case I want the table to look something like:

```
# | Type | Description | Symbol
--+------+-------------+--------
0 | 2021 | Stundenlohn | ABC
1 | 2024 | Something   | XYZ
```

this would work quite well, if I always know the names of the array keys:

```
{% for key, u in tableContent %}
    <li>{{ key }}: {{ u.Type }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

And with this I'd get `0: 2021` and `1: 2024`

is there a way to not use (in my case) Type but somehow the index?

With this solution I'm working on at the moment I only get the first value:

```
 {% for array in tableContent %}
      {% for id, key in array %}
           {{id }} | {{key}}<br/>
      {% endfor %}<br/>
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: maybe by using the keys filter and taking only the first value, this will give you the column name (key) for the first column. Then, you read the u[key] value. This is the idea (https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/keys.html)

Comment: Hi Pierre, unfortunatelly it doesn't help. I am not loop through the array and print it out with 
- first: name of the key
- and second: the value